# Use of a matrix dynamically created on python

Tags: python, matrix, dynamically-generated

I created matrix variables dynamically and I need to print each element this matrix from this matrix, but I do not know how to do.

My code:

```
est_camp1 = ['ppte', 'riod', 'onrj', 'braz']
for i in range (len (est_camp1)):
    locals () ['mvc_% s'% est_camp1 [i]] = np.matrix (np.zeros ((3,3)))
    print locals () ['mvc_% s'% est_camp1 [i]] [locals () ['% d'% i], locals () ['% d'% i]]
```

The code is creating the variables, like:

```
mvc_ppte = [[0. 0. 0.]
            [0. 0. 0.]
            [0. 0. 0.]]

mvc_riod = [[0. 0. 0.]
            [0. 0. 0.]
            [0. 0. 0.]]
```

etc...

But, I can not print `mvc_ppte [i, i]`.
If I try `print mvc_ppte [0,0]`, for example, I can print.

What can I do to fix:
`print locals () ['mvc_% s'% est_camp1 [i]] [locals () ['% d'% i], locals () ['% d'% i]]`?

Comment: First, are you sure you are not missing commas in the variable definitions? Second, what exactly is the error message when you "can not print"?

Comment: If i try to: `print locals()['mvc_%s'%est_camp1[i]]` or `print locals()['mvc_%s'%est_camp1[i]][0,0]`, I can print.
But, when I try to print, like `print mvc_ppte[i,i]` (writing with locals()...) I can't do it.
The error is:  
    File "C:/Users/Rodrigo/teste.py", line 132, in <module>
    print locals()['mvc_%s'%est_camp1[i]][locals () ['% d'% i], locals () ['% 
    d'% i]]# [locals()['%d'%i]]

KeyError: ' 0'

Comment: For `i=0`, `['% d'% i]` evaluates to `' 0'`. You do not an item with such key in `locals()`. The whole idea of messing up with the `locals` seems to be very questionable to me. Why do you have to modify the local variables through the dictionary?

Comment: I put `[['% d'% i], ['% d'% i]]` with `locals ()` to like `[i, i]`. About my choice of using locals (), it happens because it was the way I managed do it on python after searching here on stackoverflow. The problem that I put on the topic is just to understand how to do what I need. My real problem is that I have a big matrix, that could be 6x6 or 51x51, depending on the input file, and I need to process each 3x3 matrix inside that big matrix, that is, separating the block diagonals from the big matrix.